# error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'y' of 'Vector2.Vector2(float, float)'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im a beginner in C# and Code for the first time with Unity so i dont now why i get this error

> using System.Collections;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.Collections.Specialized;
> using System.Security.Cryptography;
> using UnityEngine;

public class MovementRocket : MonoBehaviour
{

```
    public float maxSpeed = 4;
    public bool lookingRight = true;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    private Animator anim;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float hor = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(hor * maxSpeed);

        float ver = Input.GetAxis("Vertikal");
        rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(ver * maxSpeed);

        if ((hor > 0 && !lookingRight) || (hor < 0 && lookingRight))
            Flip();


    }

    public void Flip()
    {
        lookingRight != lookingRight;
        Vector3 myScale = transform.localScale;
        myScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = myScale;
        myScale.y *= +1;
        transform.localScale = myScale;
        myScale.y *= -1;
        transform.localScale = myScale;
```

Comment: a `Vector2` needs _two_ arguments. you're creating two vectors with _one_ argument each.

Answer (score 1):

[`Vector2`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.html)'s [constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2-ctor.html) takes 2 arguments `Vector2(float x, float y)` but you are only providing a single float value `new Vector2(ver * maxSpeed)`.

I think this is what you intended:

```
// your code (incorrect constructor for Vector2)
float hor = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(hor * maxSpeed); // assign value to rb2d.velocity

float ver = Input.GetAxis("Vertikal");
rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(ver * maxSpeed); // overwrite value you just assigned
```

should be

```
float hor = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float ver = Input.GetAxis("Vertikal");

// create 2d vector and assign only once
rb2d.velocity = new Vector2(hor * maxSpeed, ver * maxSpeed);
```

Your rb2d.velocity will be faster when moving diagonally. There are a few steps you can take to fix this and other problems you might encounter. I recommend checking out this set of tutorials https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/movement/.

Comment: Thank you, but now i get this error error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: You should post that as a new question with more details like the code and line number

Comment: @JacobHuckins what do you mean by `a minimum`? ^^ It takes exactly two parameters ;)

Comment: @derHugo I think my brain went to constructor overloading for creating vector3's but that's definitely not how the vectors in unity work. Fixed answer.